# Repeat break Loop for created variable in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I am trying to create a while loop such that the new variable changes until the criteria is met. I am using the datatable and repeat break function but it is not working. The sample example is below.

```
X <- as.character(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"))
Y <- as.numeric(c(1,0,0,0,0,1.5,1,1,2,0))

df_sample <- data.frame(X, Y)
```

Now I would like to calculate the quartiles for each of the categories in col X starting from 0.75 to 1 such that when the quartile answer is >=1, then it stops otherwise it keeps on looping in the Quartile list specified.

Below is the Quartile list for example

```
TS_Q_list <- c(0.75,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.92,0.95,1)
```

The answer I am looking for is below. So in the example below, in row 3 the iteration stops at quartile 0.75 since the TS_Q >=1 while row 2 meets the criteria at quartile 0.85 with the answer as 1.05

```
  X obs TS_Q TS_Q2
1 A   3 1.00  1.00
2 B   3 1.05  0.85
3 C   4 1.25  0.75
```

I tried using the below code but it is not working. Can someone tell me why the below code might not work and what is the best way to go about this problem?

```
df <- setDT(df_sample)[,. (obs = .N, 
          repeat {
          j <- j + 1
          TS_Q = quantile(Y ,TS_Q_list[j], na.rm = TRUE)
          if(TS_Q<0){
            break
          }
          }
          ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I solved it I hope it works

```
df <- df_sample

TS_Q <- TS_Q2 <- NULL
q = matrix(NA,nrow=length(TS_Q_list),ncol = length(unique(df$X)))

for(i in 1:3){
    q[,i] <- quantile(subset(df, X == unique(df$X)[i])$Y, TS_Q_list)
  TS_Q[i] <- min(q[,i][q[,i] >= 1])
  TS_Q2[i] <- TS_Q_list[min(which(q[,i] >= 1))]}

data.frame(X = unique(df$X), obs = aggregate(df, list(X = X),length)[,2],
           TS_Q = TS_Q,TS_Q2 = TS_Q2)
```

Comment: Omg that is so good! Thanks so much!! I never thought of the problem that way